# Upgrading from Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Beta 2 to Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

I am running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Beta 2. When the release of Ubuntu Mate 16.04LTS on April 21 will I have to do anything to upgrade or will it just run as a normal upgrade operation?

Robert...

Comment: No. You don't..